# How to display rows with given value and display the number of rows having that value in one query?

Tags: sql

I'm creating a table to which I want to place records from another table. The first table is 'users' and it has user_id and branch columns. The table I'm creating - 'branches' has two columns branch and users_no, and in it I want to display all the branches and then count the users in all of those branches from the 'users' table in one query. I was thinking of doing SELECT COUNT statements but could not get far with it.

Comment: Provide some sample data and your expected output in tablular format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select branch, count(*)
from users
group by branch
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I'm a novice, and I didn't know that you could do select and count(*) in the same query